# Spell checker vs. Rechtschreibkorrekturprogramm

Tags: word-choice

Which word is most commonly used to refer to spell checkers?

- die Rechtschreibprüfung (dict.cc)
- das Rechtschreibprüfprogramm (leo.org)
- die Rechtschreibkontrolle (leo.org)

Which term is used? Don't people say *Spell checker*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think

> die Rechtschreibprüfung

is the most common (and IMHO the best) expression for *spell checker*.

*Rechtschreibprüfprogramm* sounds outdated. It's like saying "spell checking program." All modern spell checkers are integrated into some other software components (word processors, web browsers, online services etc.).

Comment: Do you mean that there were actual, mechanical/organic spell checkers in the old days?

Comment: @Tim no, I meant that they were stand-alone programs; software on CD-ROM that you could buy and install separately from other software.

Comment: Well, there are people who proof read texts.

Comment: @swegi ...but we don't call them "Programme" :)

Answer (score 4):

I guess the difference between these terms comes from what they do, some computer specific differences. "Rechtschreibkontrolle " is desgined for interaction between user and computer. the user works on "Rechtschreibprüfung" and "Rechtschreibkontrolle " checks the spelling with some internal dictionaries and user see the results of this process in "Rechtschreibprüfung".

- **die [Rechtschreibprüfung](http://www.at-mix.de/rechtschreibpruefung.htm)** is the program's user interface which allow users to approve replacements and modify the program's operation.

[image: Like]

- **die [Rechtschreibkontrolle](http://www.at-mix.de/rechtschreibkontrolle.htm)** will be active to check the spelling, when you run the program.
- **das Rechtschreibprüfprogramm** is the program which checks the spelling. e.g. Lingcheck

Comment: Bitte **das** Rechtschreibprüfprogramm. Es ist ein **Programm**, um die Rechtschreibung zu prüfen.

Comment: @bernd_k: Aha, danke.

Comment: Ergibt Sinn. Ist ein _Spell Checker_ alles?

Comment: @Tim:I think so, but they refer to different things.

Answer (score 2):

In einigen deutschen Softwarefirmen ist der Gebrauch von häufigen englischen Begriffen üblich. Dort kann

> Spell Checker

als Fremdwort alternativ gebraucht werden.

Rechtschreibprüfung ist keine künstliche Wortschöpfung sondern beschreibt mit geläufigen Worten genau die Funktion.

Comment: Im Gegenteil: Alle Wortschöpfungen sind künstlich, oder werden die Worte von einem Gott offenbart? Schreiben sie sich selbst ins Wörterbuch?

Comment: Das Wort _Rechtschreibprüfung_ erscheint mir nicht neu. Künstlich ist, das es als Bezeichnung einer bestimmten Sorte zu Programmen zugeordnet wurde und dadurch indirekt langfristig die Bedeutung des Wortes verändert.

Comment: Wenn es neben der Tätigkeit des Lehrers, dessen Prüfung es bislang bedeutet hat, auch eine Sorte Programm bedeuten soll, dann muss sich die Bedeutung sofort ändern - sonst könnte es ja nicht das Programm bedeuten. Man müßte dann erst 3 Jahre warten, bis man den Text über Rechtschreibprüfungen liest? Und inwiefern 'indirekt'? Was soll das heißen?

Comment: Du hast Recht. Im Kontext des Satzes hat es **sofort** die neue Bedeutung. Im Kontext eines Wörterbuches vergeht einige Zeit bis die neue zusätzliche Bedeutung aufgenommen wird und damit als fester Bestandteil der Sprache erfasst wird.